# Redirect all pages to new Subfolder under same Directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, hosting

I am manually migrating a website to a different hosting service. Everything including the domain should remain the same. There is an old site in the root directory of this hosting service that needs to be preserved, and so I'm installing the new site in a subdirectory. I have created a subdirectoy for the website and have this in the .htaccess in the root directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.org$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.org$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subfolder/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

This is redirecting the homepage correctly, but every other page is showing up with the old website view and giving a 404 error. I'm assuming there's a problem in my .htaccess, but I don't know how to locate it.

EDIT: There is an .htaccess file in the subdirectory, since it's a full wordpress install copied over from another environment. These are the contents of the file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Redirs Base Redirect:
Redirect 301 /redirs https://redirs.io/containers/?co=client-organization&con=example.org&host=WP-Engine&gsheet=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fspreadsheets%2Fd%2F19Hw1ApeEuzlW5P0e2A7aZ6lJBWCN9Kpkvtvg8LFokik%2Fedit%23gid%3D0&gfile301=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fspreadsheets%2Fd%2Fe%2F2PACX-1vRs5snE204cb7OZB-xFep5Ju9rccjKaNX-jP9Nb0yZHGlXQ-4pPh63-K8EP7YErCQwbFgYJSf52zlBP%2Fpub%3Fgid%3D0%26single%3Dtrue%26output%3Dcsv&gfile302=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fspreadsheets%2Fd%2Fe%2F2PACX-1vRs5snE204cb7OZB-xFep5Ju9rccjKaNX-jP9Nb0yZHGlXQ-4pPh63-K8EP7YErCQwbFgYJSf52zlBP%2Fpub%3Fgid%3D1333061259%26single%3Dtrue%26output%3Dcsv&gfileDomRules=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fspreadsheets%2Fd%2Fe%2F2PACX-1vRs5snE204cb7OZB-xFep5Ju9rccjKaNX-jP9Nb0yZHGlXQ-4pPh63-K8EP7YErCQwbFgYJSf52zlBP%2Fpub%3Fgid%3D1293752576%26single%3Dtrue%26output%3Dcsv&gfileDoms=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fspreadsheets%2Fd%2Fe%2F2PACX-1vRs5snE204cb7OZB-xFep5Ju9rccjKaNX-jP9Nb0yZHGlXQ-4pPh63-K8EP7YErCQwbFgYJSf52zlBP%2Fpub%3Fgid%3D547864294%26single%3Dtrue%26output%3Dcsv

# Redirects with sources which do NOT contain a query string:
RedirectMatch 301 ^/parents-of-rsym/?$ https://example.org/youth/parents-of-river/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/mens-page/?$ https://example.org/mens-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/about/what-to-expect/?$ https://example.org/what-to-expect/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/about/staff-pr/?$ https://example.org/staff/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/about/statement-of-faith/?$ https://example.org/we-believe/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/about/contact-link/?$ https://example.org/contact/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/youth-page/?$ https://example.org/youth-group-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/womens-page/womens-ministry-blog/?$ https://example.org/womens-ministry-blog/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/resources/calendar2/?$ https://example.org/calendar/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/womens-page/?$ https://example.org/womens-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/96-recipes/?$ https://example.org/womens-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/?$ https://example.org/youth-group-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/programs/youth-page-2/youth-program-info-page/?$ https://example.org/youth-group-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/video/?$ /https://arlington.online.church/?fbclid=IwAR0IjoHt20yVnYZv-lbIKlgq1o-kLr1EbbfShSba3A6hAgMuzPMbZBlCCqs
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/special-services/apologetics-forum-of-snohomish-county-afsc/?$ https://www.apologeticsforum.org
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/programs/children-s-programs/vbs-form-signup-2/?$ https://example.org/childrens-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/programs/children-s-programs/how-can-children-sit-through-church/?$ https://example.org/how-can-children-sit-through-church/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/programs/children-s-programs/?$ https://example.org/childrens-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/programs/music-ministry-2/philosophy/?$ https://example.org/worship/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/programs/music-ministry-2/song-suggestions/?$ https://example.org/music-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/programs/music-ministry-2/info-page/?$ https://example.org/music-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/programs/music-ministry-2/girls-choir-info-link/?$ https://example.org/music-ministry/4-this-time-girls-choir/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/programs/music-ministry-2/?$ https://example.org/music-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/programs/youth-page-2/?$ https://example.org/youth-group-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/programs/college-info-page-2/?$ https://example.org/young-adults/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/programs/womens-page-2/womens-ministry-pics/?$ https://example.org/womens-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/programs/womens-page-2/womens-ministry-blog/?$ https://example.org/womens-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/programs/womens-page-2/?$ https://example.org/womens-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/programs/mens-page-2/podcasts/iron-sharpens-iron/?$ https://example.org/music-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/programs/mens-page-2/podcasts/?$ https://example.org/music-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/programs/mens-page-2/men-min-pics-link/?$ https://example.org/music-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/programs/mens-page-2/current-mens-link/?$ https://example.org/music-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/programs/mens-page-2/?$ https://example.org/music-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/programs/seniors-page-2/?$ https://example.org/senior-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/programs/?$ https://example.org/#ministries-church
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/resources/altar-flower-gifts/?$ https://example.org
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/resources/news-page/past-event-link/?$ https://example.org/calendar/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/resources/news-page/?$ https://example.org/calendar/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/resources/web-links/?$ https://example.org/calendar/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/resources/visitor-survey/?$ https://example.org
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/resources/song-suggestions/?$ https://example.org/music-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/resources/sermons-page/2016/?$ https://example.org/media-library/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/resources/sermons-page/2015/?$ https://example.org/media-library/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/resources/sermons-page/2014/?$ https://example.org/media-library/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/resources/sermons-page/2013/?$ https://example.org/media-library/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/resources/sermons-page/2012/?$ https://example.org/media-library/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/resources/sermons-page/2011/?$ https://example.org/media-library/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/resources/sermons-page/2010/?$ https://example.org/media-library/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/resources/sermons-page/2009/?$ https://example.org/media-library/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/resources/sermons-page/2008/?$ https://example.org/media-library/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/resources/sermons-page/?$ https://example.org/media-library/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/resources/prayer-requests/?$ https://example.org/how-can-we-help/?ineedparam=Prayer
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/resources/subscribe-to-our-mailing-list/?$ https://example.org
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/resources/calendar2/calendar2-2/?$ https://example.org/calendar/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/resources/calendar2/calendar2/?$ https://example.org/calendar/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/resources/?$ https://example.org
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/womens-page/womens-ministry-pics/?$ https://example.org/womens-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/womens-page/?$ https://example.org/womens-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/college-info-page/?$ https://example.org/young-adults/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/children-s-programs/how-can-children-sit-through-church/?$ https://example.org/bringing-children-to-church/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/children-s-programs/nursery/?$ https://example.org/childrens-ministry/nursery/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/children-s-programs/bible-day-camp/?$ https://example.org/childrens-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/children-s-programs/kids-club/?$ https://example.org/childrens-ministry/kids-club/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/children-s-programs/?$ https://example.org/childrens-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/about/staff-pr/staff/?$ https://example.org/staff/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/about/directions-page/?$ https://example.org/about-us/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/about/service-times/?$ https://example.org/about-us/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/about/?$ https://example.org/about-us/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/mens-page/podcasts/iron-sharpens-iron/?$ https://example.org/mens-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/mens-page/podcasts/?$ https://example.org/mens-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/mens-page/men-min-pics-link/?$ https://example.org/mens-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/seniors-page/?$ https://example.org/senior-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/music-ministry/philosophy/?$ https://example.org/worship/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/music-ministry/song-suggestions/?$ https://example.org/worship/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/music-ministry/girls-choir-info-link/?$ https://example.org/music-ministry/4-this-time-girls-choir/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/music-ministry/music-ministry/?$ https://example.org/music-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/music-ministry/?$ https://example.org/music-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/missions/past-mission-teams/?$ https://example.org/missionaries/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/missions/missions/missionaries/?$ https://example.org/missionaries/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/missions/missions/?$ https://example.org/missionaries/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/missions/?$ https://example.org/missionaries/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/youth-page/youth-program-info-page/?$ https://example.org/youth-group-ministry/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/?$ https://example.org
# Redirects with sources which contain a QUERY STRING:

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: So, the "subfolder" is not present in the URL? What differentiates the old and new website URLs? Does the old website consist only of physical files? But what about static assets for the new site? Presumably these should also be rewritten? Do you have any other directives in the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Is the "old site in the root" accessed with a different hostname?

Comment: No, the subfolder should not be present in the URL; the URL should default to this subfolder. The old website is a fully functioning site, but no domain has pointed to it (until now, when I updated the DNS to the IP address for this server). There are no other directives in the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1
> ```

Unless you have an additional `.htaccess` file in the subfolder then this `RewriteRule` should also rewrite the request directly to `subfolder/index.php` (the same as the last rule). For example:

```
RewriteRule . subfolder/index.php [L]
```

Since the backreference is not required, I have also reduced the `RewriteRule` pattern to a single dot (so it matches everything except the root - which is handled by the next rule).

You were also missing the `L` flag. No more rules should be processed when this is successful.

---

**UPDATE:**

> EDIT: There is an .htaccess file in the subdirectory
>
> ```
> # BEGIN WordPress
> # The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
> # dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
> # Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
> </IfModule>
>
> # END WordPress
> ```

You can revert the root `.htaccess` file to how you had it originally, except that you should include the `L` flag on that rule and remove the slash prefix. For example:

```
:
RewriteRule (.*) subfolder/$1 [L]
```

The start and end anchors (ie. `^` and `$`) are not required on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

HOWEVER, you need to change the rules in the `/subfolder/.htaccess` file:

1. Remove the `RewriteBase` directive entirely. Note that this currently appears twice in the file (at the top and in the WP code block at the end). Both instances must be removed.
2. Remove the slash prefix on the *substitution* string in the last rule in the WordPress code block. In other words, change this:

   > ```
   > RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
   > ```

   To this:

   ```
   RewriteRule . index.php [L]
   ```

However, a potential problem with this is as the preceding comment warns... WordPress attempts to maintain this section, so you need to prevent WordPress from overriding these changes!

Comment: There is a .htaccess file in the subfolder, since I copied over all the website files from the previous hosting service. When I change the line you suggest here, the website breaks.

Comment: @NathanThreelines Please update your question with the contents of the subfolder `.htaccess` file. This will need to be changed if the site was previously hosted in the root.

Comment: Added to the question. Note the "mysite.org" was changed to "example.org" because of an error thrown by the Stack Overflow editor.